# Typescript not allowing me to set a value

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this type

```js
type FindQuery = {
    [key in keyof Partial<PrismaQuery & Course>]: string;
};
```

which results in this type :

[image]

Now in this segment of code :

```js
for (const key in query) {
    let queryValue = query[key];
}
```

**query** is of type **FindQuery**.

I am trying to assign **queryValue** but I get this error :

`Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'FindQuery'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'FindQuery'.ts(7053)`

Im kinda new to typescript so excuse me if this is a dumb question but I just cant figure out why it doesnt let me assign it.

Comment: `key` inside of `for .. in` loop is a `string` instead of `keyof FindQuery`

Comment: `let queryValue = query[(key as keyof FindQuery)];`

Comment: Oh waw I didnt know of the 'as' operator. Huh Thanks a lot it worked